# Extending A Custom Sort With A Custom Comparer

Tags: c#, linq

I have a custom sort that I am using to sort a list which works fine

```
public static void Sort<T>(ref List<T> list, string propertyName, SortDirection direction)
{
    var comparer = new CustomComparer();
    list = direction == SortDirection.Ascending
        ? list.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList()
        : list.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
}
```

now I'm trying to add a CustomComparer to the mix and I get an error when I extend the method.

> The type arguments for method 'IOrderedEnumerable
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(this
>   IEnumerable, Func, IComparer)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public static void Sort<T>(ref List<T> list, string propertyName, SortDirection direction)
{
    list = direction == SortDirection.Ascending
        ? list.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null), new CustomComparer()).ToList()
        : list.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null), new CustomComparer()).ToList();
}
```

I get that the OrderBy is not set correctly does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<object>
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of CustomComparer ? I mean does it implement IComparer or IEqualityComparer ?

Comment: I updated the question with the stub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify type arguments explicitly `<T, object>` in `OrderByDescending` method.

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<object>
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


    public static void Sort<T>(ref List<T> list, string propertyName)
    {
        list = list.OrderByDescending<T, object>(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null), new MyComparer()).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I think visual studio was screwing up. I added the <T, object> the the OrderByDecending and Resharper showed it was redundant so I removed it. After I removed it VS didn't show the compile error any longer. Sorry to waste your time however it did clear my error.